# Laravel Echo is not listening to the events

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I am working on real time notifications, I am using the following packages:
"predis/predis": "^1.1"
"laravel-echo": "^1.4.0",
"io": "^1.0.0",
"socket.io": "^2.1.1",
"socket.io-client": "^2.4.0"

I also downgraded the socke.io-client version and also added dot "." before event name. But I don't get any response on my frontend. Can anybody help me out

My laravel-echo-server configurations are

```
{
    "authHost": "http://localhost:8000",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

And my .env file is

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

My TestEvent

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NotificationEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow 
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $message ;
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('notification-event');
    }

    // public function broadcastAs()
    // {
    //     return 'notification-event';
    // }
}
```

Bootstrap.js

```
window.axios = require('axios');
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

and my frontend

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </head>
    <body>

      <script src="{{asset('js\app.js')}}"></script>
      <!-- <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script> -->
      <script>
        Echo.channel('notification-event')
        .listen('.NotificationEvent', (e) => {
            swal('Notification', e.message);
            });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Route

```
Route::get('send_test_event', function () {
        event(new App\Events\NotificationEvent('Is online now'));
        return "Event has been sent!";
    });
```

This is the laravel-echo-server output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHJHQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

make these changes and see if it works or not

.ENV file

`BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis`
`QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis`

in Bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.io = require('socket.io-client');


window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'socket.io',
host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
withCredentials: true

});
```

in echo-server config

```
"socketio": {
    "cors": {
        "origin": "http://localhost",
        "credentials": true
    }
},
```

you should run php artisan queue:listen or queue:work  before firing events

Comment: and if you dont want to use insert these extra lines then just downgrade your socket.io-client to  "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0"...npm i socket.io-client@2.3.0.  [sameIssue](https://github.com/laravel/echo/issues/290)